# Prevent div from losing focus

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to prevent div from losing focus on specific actions ?

I have grid like an excel. Each cell - `div` element has `blur` event, `onclick`, `onkeydown`.

`onKeyDown` method:

```
    onKeyDown(event) {
        const { keyCode } = event;
        let element;

        switch (keyCode) {
        case 13:
            // Key: ENTER
            if (this.isEditingAllowed) {
                element = document.querySelector(`.keyboard-navigable-${this.column}-${this.row}`);
                // I would love to stop propagation of that event here - do not call a blur !!
            }
            break;
        case 37:
            // Key: LEFT
            element = document.querySelector(`.keyboard-navigable-${this.column - 1}-${this.row}`);

            break;
        case 38:
            // Key: UP
            element = document.querySelector(`.keyboard-navigable-${this.column}-${this.row - 1}`);

            break;
        case 39:
        case 9:
            // Key: RIGHT || TAB
            element = document.querySelector(`.keyboard-navigable-${this.column + 1}-${this.row}`);
            if (!element) {
                // We get out of bounds - go to the next line
                element = document.querySelector(`.keyboard-navigable-0-${this.row + 1}`);
            }

            break;
        case 40:
            // Key: DOWN
            element = document.querySelector(`.keyboard-navigable-${this.column}-${this.row + 1}`);

            break;
        default: break;
        }

        if (element) {
            element.focus();
        }
    }
```

As we can see on `enter` key I would love to stop propagating this event for not allowing to call blur - why ? I do have conditional rendering of other elements when we enter in editing mode. I do not wanna lost context tho of the element behind. `.preventDefault()` or `.stopPropagation()` does not work. And I need to listen for `blur` events because same elements has `onclick` events as well and I do not wanna store anywhere `selectedDOMElement` to `.blur()` it if exists in `onclick` method when we have native support for it.

Is there any other way to stop blur / keep the focus of the "parent" element when we press for example `enter` key ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to loose focus to the input field, then don't do it.

```
case 13:
    // Key: ENTER
    if (this.isEditingAllowed) {
        // simply remove this so that later you don't move the new input field:
        // element = document.querySelector(`.keyboard-navigable-${this.column}-${this.row}`);
    }
    break;
...
if (element) {
    element.focus(); // this is YOU telling the previous element to loose focus ;-)
}
```

Comment: I know that `.focus` makes my element to call `.blur`. It is included in the question, not directly tho. Sorry If my question wasn't clear.

Comment: What exactly do you want? Press enter, but don't loose focus of the field? Then comment out the code as I showed you.